# C++ Count open sockets used by Program

Tags: c++, sockets

I need a way to count all open sockets which are currenty created by a program I wrote. 
Is there a simple way in c++ how to handle this?

I need something like:
Your Program is using xxx Sockets currently.

The Problem with this Program is, that it opens up a modbus-connection (libmodbus-3.0.5) and I don't know if my code works and closes the sockets properly if there is no connection and/or after use.

Due to the limitations of the embedded (linux based) system the program will run on, there is no way using something like boost.

Thanks in advance

Robboe

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do this? Tried this one but got confused by the output (yeah I'm really new to this stuff :-) )

Comment: Tried it with netstat --protocol=inet -c is there a way to count the output lines or entries?

Comment: i don't know which port you are using or the name of your program... i don't even know if your system is a *nix. manpages always help... however try this `netstat --protocol=inet -p | grep [your program name] | wc` for the very first time. it's not the best thing to do...